# Including 'of' in unit qualifiers with siunitx

Tags: siunitx

I need to use units like

> kg/kg of air

or

> kg of water/kg of air

How can I do it with `siunitx`?

Comment: Jake: Sorry, I learn by examples...siunitx manual contains lot of options...with little examples... I just started using siunitx. Once again sorry Jake

Comment: @sandu -- your claim that the siunitx user guide contains few examples seems odd. The package provides lots of options, but the guide also provides plenty of examples illustrating the available option.

Comment: But still it is hard to understand for a person new to LaTeX. One of the challenges with LaTeX is that there are so many different syntaxes, ‘every package has its own’.

Comment: Sveinung: Yes you are correct. It takes time to understand and use different syntaxes...Initially we need help to customize a package to our requirements.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Updated answer

With the current release of `siunitx`, the command `\of` using the `qualifier-mode = phrase` option covers this case:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{per-mode = symbol,qualifier-mode = phrase}
\begin{document}
\SI{10}{\kg\of{water}\per\kg\of{air}}
\end{document}
```

### Original answer

These look like 'qualifiers'. At present, there is not a mode to include 'of' or similar (perhaps I should add that), so you need a little imagination

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIQualifier{\air}{of air}
\DeclareSIQualifier{\water}{of water}
\sisetup{per-mode = symbol,qualifier-mode = space}
\begin{document}
\SI{10}{\kg\water\per\kg\air}
\end{document}
```

A more 'standard' approach would be something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIQualifier{\air}{air}
\DeclareSIQualifier{\water}{water}
\begin{document}
\SI{10}{\kg\water\per\kg\air}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @sandu Just so you know, Mr. Wright went ahead and added it, so there's now a `\of` command.

Comment: @Arafinwe Thanks for the reminder about this question: I've edited the answer!

Comment: @JosephWright Hello, I have one request about your package `siunitx`.  When one uses `per-mode = symbol`, `\SI{1e4}{\per\s}` returns `10^4/s`.  According to ISO 80000 this is wrong, it should be written `10^4 s^{-1}`.  I think it would be a good idea to put an option into your package, which overrides `per-mode` format for in-line mode and goes into normal mode when unit starts with `\per`.  Thanks and best regards.

Comment: @Pygmalion If you are following the 'rules' you'd never use `per-mode = symbol` in any case :-) The current output is I'd say the most consistent for the user: per as a symbol means exactly that, so producing an exponent would be confusing for most people. (Note: ISOs are regrettably not freely available, and so I can only go on what I have access to.)

Comment: @JosephWright Acoording to ISO-80000 (according to which **all** other standards use notation rules), both `m/s` and `m s^{-1}` are allowed, but `/s` is not.  Of course one can do that manually, but this is really tedious.  At least `per-mode=exponent` or `per-mode=default` would be useful to prevent `per-mode=symbol` in cases when unit starts with `\per`.

Comment: @Pygmalion I've logged this as https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/issues/234. I'm currently busy with other TeX and non-TeX things, but would hope to tackle this at some stage in the next few months. My initial though is this is doable without too much effort, although I'll need to work out a consistent option name.

Comment: @JosephWright Thank you very much.  Won't help my book which is going to be printed in two weeks, but I am sure someone else will need this!  (If none else, me writing the next book ;-)