# How to use the 'qualifiers' in siunitx?

Tags: siunitx

This question is extention of [Including 'of' in unit qualifiers with siunitx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59037/how-to-define-unit-in-siunitx)

I need

> 10 kg of water/m^3 of air

How to get this...following code does not give this...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIQualifier{\air}{of air}
\DeclareSIQualifier{\water}{of water}
\sisetup{per-mode = symbol,qualifier-mode = space}
\begin{document}
\SI{10}{\kg\water\per\kg\air}
%
10~kg of water/m$^3$ of air\\
\SI{10}{\kg\water\per\m\cubed\air}\\
\end{document}
```

Comment: Since you are working with the qualifier `of air`, it seems to me that the correct thing is the `m of air` that is cubed, hence the `10 kg of water/(m of air)^3` make sense, which is what `siunitx` is producing.

Comment: I mean 10 kg of water for every one m^3 of air. so 10 kg of water/(m of air)^3 does not make sense here.

Comment: I am no expert on this, it seems that you should either **not** use the `qualifier-mode = space` setting, or simply use `\SI{10}{\kg\water\per\m\cubed} of air`.  Perhaps someone more knowledgeable can help you further.

Comment: I think Peter's right, the best thing to do here is probably to just put `of air` after the unit. This isn't SI notation, or commonly used notation. I've been trying to find a journal article where "<something> / m3 of <something>" is used, but found only [one from 1983](https://www.crops.org/publications/sssaj/abstracts/48/1/SS0480010003). The best thing might be to look at publications from your field and see how they do it. I would probably go with "The water content of the air is 10kg/m3", which is correct SI notation.

Comment: In text book it is given as 10 kg of water/m^3 of air

Comment: Using `(\m\cubed)` will give you the correct power. However, I'm not sure if it's possible to avoid the parentheses which are then automatically set (cf. the description of `qualifier-mode` in the `siunitx` manual, there doesn't seem to be an option to turn off the auto-detection of parentheses).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

'Quantifiers' are essentially tied to a particular unit, for expressing the idea that a unit is related to one part of a system. This is *not* the way these things are 'officially' supposed to be dealt with, but are common enough to be useful. On the other hand, there is a limit to the amount that can be covered by an automated system. In particular, raising a 'qualified' unit to a power is normally taken as applying the power to the entire thing, for example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIQualifier{\cat}{cat}
\begin{document}
\SI{10}{\mmol\per\kg\cat}
is the same as
$10$\,mmol\,kg$_{\textrm{cat}^{-1}}
\end{document}
```

Dealing with a case where you want to 'qualify' a unit raised to a power is probably beyond the boundaries of what can be squeezed into the standard interface. I would therefore set up a special 'unit' for this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit{\mcubedair}{m^{3}\text{ of air}}
\sisetup{per-mode = symbol}
\begin{document}
\SI{10}{\kg\per\mcubedair}
\end{document}
```